# Encode Forward Slash with &#x2F in Text area drupal 7 form

Tags: forms

I am facing issue in Encoding forward slash with &#x2F in my custom drupal 7 form.
I have a text area field with name "Address", i am using check_plain for encode special characters, All HTML related tags are getting encoded, but i want to encode forward slash(/) as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to get the unencoded string from the text area and encode the string in PHP?

Comment: [`check_plain`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7.x) in D7 just calls `htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` which only translates a limited number of characters. Depending on what you want to do, you may want to use [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) instead? Or just maybe even do a plain old `str_replace()` (or `preg_replace`...) if you only want to translate 1 character?

Comment: Yes, i am taking unencoded input  / in textarea  and encode this with &#x2f.                   $company->setAttribute('Address',check_plain($form_state['values']['Address']));

Comment: I am curious why you would want to encode even the /. / is an HTML safe character. Where are you using the encoded data? Are you printing it in HTML? Passing it as parameters to a URL? Sending it in a REST call?

Comment: Did the answer below help you address the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following to convert all characters you want to convert into their corresponding HTML entity version. I have added a check on converting only non alpha-numeric characters into HTML entities. You can add a different logic to convert only those characters you want to convert (in the if condition with ctype_alum)

The following is adapted from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005240/722087)

```
function encode($str) {
  $str = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8'); //big endian
  $split = str_split($str, 4);

  $res = "";
  $pos = 0;
  foreach ($split as $c) {
    // Check if the character is alpha numeric and
    // if not, convert to HTML entity.
    if (!ctype_alnum ($str[$pos])) {
      $cur = 0;
      for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $cur |= ord($c[$i]) << (8*(3 - $i));
      }
      $res .= "&#" . $cur . ";";
    }
    else {
      $res .= $str[$pos];
    }
    $pos++;
  }
  return $res;
}
```